# How do I access the search functionality in Open Office?

Tags: search, openoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice

I am very new to oo and plodding slowly; never used a spreadsheet, etc.etc.
I downloaded a document of botanical names for flowers/herbs, etc.  The page was set in 3 columns and was 138 pages long (!)  My most important question is, I am trying to look for a certain name but it is a nightmare (so very much) and wonder is there an oo search capacity to do this (I humbly ask: PLEASE>>laymans terms)

My second question is, when I transported the 3 column document into the spreadsheet (it had 12 columns I think) I tried reading how to adjust the columns, couldn't figure it out, so I just held the mouse down and moved the unused columns over to the far right where I couldn't see them =)  Any help in your own words, or instructions in your own words would be very very helpful if you have the time.  I do read a lot, but find there is SO much information and if you don't ALREADY know the >definitions< of what you are trying to read/comprehend (cell?) you can be lost before you even start to find the answer.

Please help an old woman if you have the time and inclination.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

The search function is located under the "Edit" menu, and can also be reached by it's keyboard shortcut which is pressing Ctrl (or Cmd on a Mac) and F simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

For the 1st question, as Riyaah already answered, you can use the locate and substitute function under edit menu. You can also sort the data by the column you want "painting" the whole set of data with the mouse and selecting in the menu DATA -> SORT and selecting which column you want to sort by.

For the 2nd question, if you want to delete the column, you can select the whole column with your mouse clicking on the upper cell with the "Name" of the column (for example "B" to select the 2nd column) and hit the DEL key to delete the whole content (the column will be blank) but if you want to REMOVE the whole column, you select the whole column the same way and on the right button menu, you select "REMOVE COLUMN" or something like that (my oo is not in english, anyways it's located below "Insert column").

Now, if you want to move the column, you select the whole column in the same way and hit the right mouse button, select CUT and place the cursor where you want to put the moved column, click right button and select PASTE.

If you want to resize the column, you drag the vertical side of the upper cell of the column (the cell with the letter of the name of the column) (you will see the cursor changing to `<=>` when you are at the right place).

The same "moves" can be applied to rows (except sorting).

Good luck!